# Reading from txt file each line as Array

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm working on Winform app that takes employees data as an array of 4 elements 
and correctly save these data to a text file in one line WITH SEPARATOR (",")..

My question is how to make it load any lines data and recognize the separator (",")
so that I can get it to read all data by the first item which is name?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] data = new string[4];
        string name;
        string job;
        string salary;
        string join;

        #region Save


void save()
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill All Fields", "error");
        }

        FileStream file = new FileStream("info.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
        wr.WriteLine(String.Join(",", data));
        wr.Flush();
        wr.Close();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(data[0]);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();

    }
    #endregion

    #region Search
    void search()
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream("info.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
        sr.ReadLine(string.//what should i do here?
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("info.txt");
        data[0].CompareTo(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        sr.ReadLine();
        if (data[0] == name)
        {
            textBox1.Text = (data[0]);
            textBox2.Text = (data[1]);
            textBox3.Text = (data[2]);
            textBox4.Text = (data[3]);
        }
    } 
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply read the file back again, and use Split on the delimiter you have chosen

```
        var textLines = File.ReadAllLines("");

        foreach (var line in textLines)
        {
            string[] dataArray = line.Split(',');
        }
```

Comment: i did and followed it's action using F11 , successfully got all items but.. still doesn't write these data into textboxes!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked , line split in to array data ,
each added in the right text box :

```
void search()
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream("info.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
            sr.ReadLine();
            var textLines = File.ReadAllLines("info.txt");

            foreach (var line in textLines)
            {
                string[] dataArray = line.Split(',');
                dataArray[0].CompareTo(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                if (dataArray[0] == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                   textBox1.Text = (dataArray[0]);
                   textBox2.Text = (dataArray[1]);
                   textBox3.Text = (dataArray[2]);
                   textBox4.Text = (dataArray[3]); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks alot mr.Jun Wei Lee

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
                int size, string filePath);
 /// <summary>
        /// read value from given section and key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Section">string</param>
        /// <param name="Key">string</param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
 public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                            255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();

        }
```

To call this function See Below Code

```
 string[] sBENCHNO=new Strin[256];
     sBENCHNO = ini.IniReadValue("Sextion", "Key");
```